# PHP MVC: How to add translation strings to views?

Tags: php

In my MVC view files, there exist strings I may have a translation for. In a file with access to the database (the model), I can do:

```
$Lang->say('Welcome');
```

Here is what it's doing:

```
public function say($string) {

    if (empty(self::$vocabulary)) {
        self::$vocabulary = $this->loadLanguage($this->currentLanguageID()); // Load vocabulary for current language
    }

    if (isset(self::$vocabulary[$string])) {
        return self::$vocabulary[$string];  
    } 

    return $string;

}
```

I need access to this `say()` function from within my view. Short of passing the entire vocabulary array to the view, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is `require_once` your **.php** file that contains your class. You can then instantiate your class into a object like `$Lang` and call `$Lang->Say()` from your view.

For example:

```
require_once "file_that_holds_class.php";

$Lang = new classNameHere();
$result = $obj->Say("whatever_string_value");

echo $result;
```

Now you can do whatever it is you need to do with the string.